# Getting white icon for instance in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have registered one new server but showing white icon instead of green. But my other colleagues can able to see green icon while registering the server.

I have given sysadmin access to me on that instance, still not able to see and checked WMI service on target server and refresh ssms entry many times.

Even I could not able to see always on availability on this instance but other can.

[image]

And this is a cluster server.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The white icon means you have no permissions to start\stop service. It's not enough to be sysadmin on the server, you should have windows permissions.

This article describes how to give these permissions:
[How to Grant Users Rights to Manage Services (Start, Stop, Etc.)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5752.how-to-grant-users-rights-to-manage-services-start-stop-etc.aspx)